Playwright: Element Not Empty After Clearing Input in Headed Mode
General IOnformation:
I'm encountering an issue with Playwright in headed mode. I have an input field that I wait for and then clear, but when I check if it's empty, the test fails with a timeout error. Below is the relevant code and the stack trace.
Code:
await qaElementPropertyEditorLabelInput().waitFor();
await qaElementPropertyEditorLabelInput().clear();

await expect(
  qaElementPropertyEditorLabelInput(),
  "Label property field is empty now"
).toBeEmpty();

Error Message:
Error: Label property field is empty now

Timed out 30000ms waiting for expect(locator).toBeEmpty()

Locator: locator('.qa-property-editor-label-property').locator(locator('.qa-rte-content')).or(locator('.qa-property-editor-label-property').locator(locator('.qa-text-field').locator('input')))
Expected: empty
Received: notEmpty
Call log:
  - Label property field is empty now with timeout 30000ms
  - waiting for locator('.qa-property-editor-label-property').locator(locator('.qa-rte-content')).or(locator('.qa-property-editor-label-property').locator(locator('.qa-text-field').locator('input')))
  -   locator resolved to <span tabindex="0" translate="no" contenteditable="tru…>…</span>
  -   unexpected value "not empty"
  -   locator resolved to <span tabindex="0" translate="no" contenteditable="tru…>…</span>
  -   unexpected value "not empty"
  ...

The locator resolved to a span element repeatedly, indicating the input field was not cleared properly.
Code:
       await Promise.all([
          qaElementPropertyEditorLabelInput().waitFor(),
          qaElementPropertyEditorLabelInput().clear(),
          expect(
              qaElementPropertyEditorLabelInput(),
              "Label property field is empty now"
          ).toBeEmpty()
        ]);

One more thing When I use promise all like that, it looks like working but I can't be sure which is the best approach.
Extra Information:
When I run the same test in headless mode, it works without problems. In headed mode when I clear the input, no network action is triggered; only some DOM element attributes change.
By the way to see the result when I add hard wait for 1-2 seconds, even it is in headed mode test is passing.
Question:
How can I fight that flakiness and how to wait without using hard waits in Playwright? What should I have to wait? Element, text, dom attribute etc?

Please share a [mcve] with the site (or a reproducible sample of the relevant behavior) and your full (but minimal) automation code. Without that, there's no way to help here. "how can I fight common flakiness in tests?" is far too broad to be in scope--there are a million ways a test can be flakey. The only answer that isn't an essay is "follow Playwright's best practices".

Unfortunately, I can't do that. If possible, please try to use the provided data.

You haven't provided any data, though, just some undefined functions. What's stopping you from creating a reprex, except effort? Cook up a simple, reproducible site that features the problematic behavior and show your complete sample test for it. From the link I shared above: "Restart from scratch. Create a new program, adding in only what is needed to see the problem." (Yes, this takes a bit of work)

We use only qa-classes to select elements in our application. Since our application supports multiple languages, we avoid using text-based or other types of selectors. I've reviewed best practices but haven't found any guidelines specifically addressing the use of custom qa-classes. Does this mean our current approach is incorrect?

Can't say without seeing the app (or a reprex of it) and the test, and that generic advice doesn't seem related to the test failure you're seeing.

okay, thanks for sharing your time :)

Please add some more info. BTW - did you try locator.fill("")?

I didn't try that! I will try it as soon as possible thank you for the idea :) What is difference between these two?

the main problem was caused by "hydration" issues in the UI.
I found a working solution by using the expect.toPass() function provided by Playwright.
await expect(async () => {
    await qaSliderPropertyEditorStepSizeInput().waitFor();
    await qaSliderPropertyEditorStepSizeInput().clear();

    await expect(qaSliderPropertyEditorStepSizeInput()).toBeEmpty({timeout: 500});
}).toPass();

await expect(async () => {
    expect(qaSliderPropertyEditorStepSizeError(), "Step size property field displays an error now").toBeVisible();
}).toPass();

This approach ensures that the input field is properly cleared and prevents flakiness in the tests.
Feel free to add any additional details or context as needed!

